# Adding up the values with the same index using numpy/python

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

I am a newbie to python and numpy. I want to find the total rainfall days (ie. sum of column E for each year, attach the image herewith).
I am using **numpy.unique** to find the unique elements of array year.

following is my attempt;

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("location/ofthe/file", delimiter = " ")
unique_year = np.unique(data[:,0], return_index=True)
print(unique_year)
j= input('select one of the unique year: >>>  ')
#Then I want to give the sum of the rainfall days in that year.
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such tasks, Pandas (which builds on NumPy) is more easily adaptable.

Here, you can use `GroupBy` to create a series mapping. You can then use your input to query your series:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

# create series mapping from GroupBy object
rain_days_by_year = df.groupby('year')['Rain days(in numbers)'].sum()

# get input as integer
j = int(input('select one of the unique year: >>>  '))

# extract data
res = rain_days_by_year[j]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the purpose of this exercise is to familiarize with Numpy and we were told to use Numpy. Do you have any idea how this can be implemented using Numpy? Thanks in advance.